# How to hash twice a string C openssl

Tags: c, hash, openssl, sha256

my goal is to hash with sha256 a string twice, but I don't have a good result
Here's the code :

```
void double_hash(char *string, char output[65]) {
    unsigned char out[32];
    char hash[65];
    unsigned char scnd_hash[65];
    SHA256_CTX sha256;
    SHA256_Init(&sha256);
    SHA256_Update(&sha256, string, strlen(string));
    SHA256_Final(out, &sha256);
    for (int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        sprintf(hash + (i * 2), "%02x", out[i]);
    }
    SHA256_CTX sha256_2;
    SHA256_Init(&sha256_2);
    SHA256_Update(&sha256_2, hash, strlen(hash));
    SHA256_Final(scnd_hash, &sha256_2);
    for (int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        sprintf(output + (i * 2), "%02x", scnd_hash[i]);
    }
}
```

With the string "hello" it does :

```
hello
2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824
d7914fe546b684688bb95f4f888a92dfc680603a75f23eb823658031fff766d9
```

But I want :

```
hello
2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824
9595c9df90075148eb06860365df33584b75bff782a510c6cd4883a419833d50
```

I've tried with this code but it don't produce the good result :

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void double_hash(char *string, char output[65]) {
    unsigned char out[32];
    unsigned char scnd_hash[65];
    SHA256_CTX sha256;
    SHA256_Init(&sha256);
    SHA256_Update(&sha256, string, strlen(string));
    SHA256_Final(out, &sha256);
    SHA256_CTX sha256_2;
    SHA256_Init(&sha256_2);
    SHA256_Update(&sha256_2, out, strlen((char *)out));
    SHA256_Final(scnd_hash, &sha256_2);
    for (int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        sprintf(output + (i * 2), "%02x", scnd_hash[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    char outp[65];
    char *hello = "hello";
    double_hash(hello, outp);
    printf("%s", outp);
}
```

It produce
`852d59ce6fb3099c9d563870d298f0108eff079e1dde63e66c68d2e0b40353c1`

Thank you

Comment: What does the code that gives you random results look like?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I was wrong it don't produce a random result but still wrong, I have updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To end up with `9595c9df9007...`, perform the 2nd hash on the 32-byte binary data, not on the *string*.

```
// SHA256_Update(&sha256_2, hash, strlen(hash));
SHA256_Update(&sha256_2, out, 32);
```

Ref: [SHA256](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html)